# Gem available for doing indentation in gedit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using linux system for rails development. Any gem available for doing indentation in gedit.

Answer (score 2):

Gedit has indentation built in - just enable it in Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> Enable automatic indentation

You may also want to install GMate. It's gedit + selected plugins. It's aim is to imitate TextMate. Install with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-on-rails/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate gedit-plugins
```

GMate's repo is https://github.com/gmate/gmate